# Using a Column-Count grid messed with my lightbox images

Tags: image, grid, image-resizing, lightbox2, column-count

I wanted to use a column-count grid to help make it easier with making my portfolio gallery responsive. I'm redoing my site so for the lightbox coding it's all the same from my previous one and it worked fine.

However, once I got the grid correct I noticed now when I click my images to scale to their larger size, they expand to the whole page no matter what size my images are. It works fine if I remove the grids. Any suggestions on what could be the problem?

Here is my html of the gallery:

```html
<div id="portfolio">
 <div id="gallery">
    <a href="images/PIC_1.png" data-lightbox="portfolio" ><img src="images/pic1.png" alt=""></a>
     <a href="images/PIC_2.png" data-lightbox="portfolio" ><img src="images/pic2.png" alt=""></a>
     <a href="images/PIC_3.png" data-lightbox="portfolio" ><img src="images/pic3.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="images/PIC_4.png" data-lightbox="portfolio" ><img src="images/pic4.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="images/PIC_5.png" data-lightbox="portfolio" ><img src="images/pic5.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="images/PIC_6.png" data-lightbox="portfolio" ><img src="images/pic6.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css of the gallery:

```css
#gallery{width: 880px;
  position: absolute;
          top: 70px;
          left: 310px;
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-column-count:2;
  -webkit-column-gap:5px;
  -moz-column-count:2;
  -moz-column-gap:5px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap:5px;}
#gallery img{padding-bottom: 6px;}
```

And the lightbox css:

```css
/* Preload images */
body:after {
  content: url(../images/close.png) url(../images/loading.gif) url(../images/prev.png) url(../images/next.png);
  display: none;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.lightboxOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: black;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
}

.lightbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.lightbox .lb-image {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.lightbox a img {
  border: none;
}

.lb-outerContainer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: none;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
}

.lb-outerContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.lb-container {
  padding: 4px;
}

.lb-loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  left: 0;
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
}

.lb-cancel {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat;
}

.lb-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.lb-container > .nav {
  left: 0;
}

.lb-nav a {
  outline: none;
  background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==');
}

.lb-prev, .lb-next {
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-prev {
  width: 34%;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  background: url(../images/prev.png) left 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-prev:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-next {
  width: 64%;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  background: url(../images/next.png) right 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-next:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.lb-dataContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.lb-dataContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.lb-data {
  padding: 0 4px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.lb-data .lb-details {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}

.lb-data .lb-caption {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.lb-data .lb-number {
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

.lb-data .lb-close {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(../images/close.png) top right no-repeat;
  text-align: right;
  outline: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.lb-data .lb-close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: So now I'm not feeling it's a problem with the column-count, because I checked in other browsers and it worked just fine in all besides FireFox. I can't see why this would be however, because I use lightbox in my old site and it works fine on Firefox. Any ideas? I could really use the help.